# How to set full width and full height div inside an relative and absolute div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a different scenario. There are three different div inside each other. first div has `position:relative` and second div has its `position:aboslute` now how can I stretch third div with full width and full height?

div1: `positon:relative; width:50px; height:50px;`

div2: `postion:absolute; width:50px; height:50px;`

div3: `postion:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; // It's not working`

```
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
         <!-- I need div3 with full width and full height -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `position: fixed` will solve that if you don't want the 3:rd div to scroll with page, but if you do want that, then, is the left/top position of div 1 and div 2 known? ... If not, you will need a script, if yes, let me know how that is known and I post one, if not one of the given already show how to

Comment: If div 1 is centered, both vertical and horizontal and the same goes for div 2, that does also count as having its position known.

Answer (score 1):

Why does `.div3` need to be a child of the others? Would it not be better to have:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<div class="div3"></div>
```

?

If not, does

```
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

solve your problem?

Comment: How it will works if div1 and div2 have small width and hegith?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the closest relatively positioned parent. Removing `.div3` from the other two makes the closest relative parent the document body.

Comment: This would be the appropriate solution to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

set height to first `relative` div second and other one `width 100% , height 100%` check with this snippet

```css
.div1 {
 position:relative;
 height:300px;
 width:100%;
}
.div2 {
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 left:0;
 width:50%;
 background:#999;
}
.div3 {
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:50%;
 right:0;
 background:#CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
         <!-- I need div3 with full width and full height -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How it will works if `div1` and `div2` have small width and hegith?

Comment: postion:absolute div can take full width and height to the parent relative div

Comment: check now, its changed

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  }

.div1{
 height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
}

.div2{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:absolute;
  background:gold;
}

.div3{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
         <!-- I need div3 with full width and full height -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

have a look on above solution

Comment: How it will works if `div1` and `div2` have small width and hegith?

Comment: Actually you did not mention the width and height of first and second div. but no issue I have made some changes as per your code! Have a look

Answer (score 0):

HTML + CSS just can't do it. It break the rules. If you need 3 to be bigger than 2 or 1.
You can archive that result using javascript.

[check the example](https://jsfiddle.net/kkobold/ghazeno9/)

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">
      <div class="div3">
         <!-- I need div3 with full width and full height -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

JQUERY JS

```
$('.div3').detach().insertAfter('.div1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .div2 could be anywhere in the page and you'd still want .div3 full width and full height of the viewport... top left corner positioned at the top left corner of your screen/viewport I guess (an overlay)? Otherwise a large part of it will be invisible outside the right side of the viewport (and below the bottom).

You can then use **vh** and **vw** units which are relative to the viewport whatever the size of its parents and **`position: fixed`** to move it relative to the viewport, because you don't know where .div2 is and more it's irrelevant. Here's a snippet:

```css
.div1 {
  position:relative; width:50px; height:50px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 70px;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.div3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7);
}
.div3:after {
  content: 'right bottom';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0; right: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">
     In the page, somewhere
      <div class="div3">
         <!-- I need div3 with full width and full height -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio harum quaerat accusantium ex aliquid, quia, velit saepe quisquam iure! Nobis quam asperiores saepe, in voluptatem et, harum minima a necessitatibus.
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```